# Am I missing something vs anything

Tags: idiomatic-language

"Am I missing something?" or "Am I missing anything?":

I can see how there is a subtle difference in the meaning but is one of these idiomatic?

Comment: They're both fine, and it would be splitting hairs to claim any *semantic* difference. But ***something*** is [significantly more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Am+I+missing+something%2CAm+I+missing+anything&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAm%20I%20missing%20something%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAm%20I%20missing%20anything%3B%2Cc0) for this exact utterance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

This is more widely used, colloquial, idiomatic and grammatical as well. For example:

- "Wait a second, am I missing something here?"
- "Am I missing something if I don't travel abroad?"

> Am I missing anything?

This is equally idiomatic and grammatical. However its usage is (quite) low as compared to ***am I  missing something***.

- "Am I missing anything if I don't socialize?"
- "Am I missing anything if I don't accompany you to the wedding ceremony?"

However I feel, *something* refers to a small range of objectifiable things, whereas *anything* indicates a far bigger range.

[missing something vs missing anything](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=am%20I%20missing%20something%2Cam%20I%20missing%20anything&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cam%20I%20missing%20something%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20I%20missing%20anything%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that ***something*** can be used in a more general way for when you are referring to any arbitrary number of ***things*** while ***anything*** would be better suited when the ***things*** are limited in numbers.